# Dealing with two input arguments to ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I have a set of points (several independent files of different regions) and I want to make a selection according to a set of polygons (multiple files that form pairs with the points files). I want to use them to select by location through modelbuilder.

I want to inform only once the arguments, as is done, for instance, on batch processing. I have two interdependent arguments: each point layer/file should be selected by it's corresponding polygon layer/file (mask).

Is there a feature in the modelbuilder for this purpose?
Any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Iterate Feature Classes](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/iterate-feature-classes.htm) to iterate over the features classes in the folders:

> Iterates over feature classes in a Workspace or Feature Dataset.

[Learn how Iterate Feature Classes works in ModelBuilder](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/modelbuilder-toolbox/examples-of-using-iterators-in-modelbuilder.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_46903073A36D4E928AAFC0F0AE5240EC)

Comment: I didn't get how to inform which target file (point) correspond to each mask file (polygon). They are not in a same layer separeted by attributes, but in different files. I keep trying to make this model works. Thank you.

Comment: You dont need to when they are sorted the same in the folders as in the screenshot

Comment: You can also run model in batch mode: Right click the blue inputs and set as parameters, save and close the model, right click the model and run in batch mode. You can now specify multiple inputs

Comment: I was able to make batch option, but it results error. I was unable to perform the option with "iterate classes".

1) Batch option - I prepared the model by selecting the shapefiles as parameters. When I run individually it works. When I use the Batch option, It is created the play list, ok.  But when I execute, seeing the log, the processing seems to be out of order (executes all "make layers", then all "select by location", and don't give back a coherent result). Do you know why does it happens?

Comment: 2) I was not able to create the model with "Iterate Feature Classes". I have two folders (workspace) - points and mask. The Iterate Feature Classes seems to only accept one workspace at each time. I don't know if I have to add 2 Iterate Feature Classes (the modelbuilder does not allow) or if I should put both folders as subfolders of a single one and then divide them at the entrance of "select by location" (not sure how).

Comment: The Batch option worked. The problem was on the output folder. If you could help me on the  "Iterate Feature Classes" option I would appreciate a lot. It seems to be very useful. Thank you Bjorn.